# Complete Graph Invariant

Tags: graph-theory

A graph invariant $I(G)$ is called complete if the identity of the invariants $I(G)$ and $I(H)$ implies the isomorphism of the graphs $G$ and $H$. Is there any example for complete graph invariant?

Comment: I doubt there are any nice examples for general graphs, but surely there are for some special cases, one of them being trees (look for tree isomorphism algorithms), or any other classes that has nice graph-isomorphism algorithms.

Comment: "...and if $I(G) \neq I(H)$ then $G$ and $H$ are non-isomorphic" is missing from the definition.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any evidence that there are any intuitive examples. (I'm excluding things such as assigning every equivalence class of graphs a unique integer and using that, or trying to rearrange their adjacency matrices so they are the same, etc.) There is a more in-depth discussion of this problem [over at MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11631/complete-graph-invariants) that goes into more detail about this question.

Comment: What would you consider a useful example?  Canonical labelling software, e.g. nauty, is in widespread use for a range of real-world applications.  This sounds useful to me.

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones You're right, I think useful was a very poor choice of words considering that. Maybe it's more accurate to say that there's no intuitive example?

Comment: I somewhat understand what you're trying to say: we can't expect something like "the number of 4 cycles" to work (in fact, this would imply the [graph isomorphism problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem) belonging to P).

Comment: That's a great example of what I meant- sorry for not clarifying that better. I'm trying to find a good way to express that idea- some kind of distinction between the kind of structural properties in "human language," like the number of 4 cycles, $k$-connectedness, etc; and the ways that a computer program can canonically label a graph. But this is not my strongest area in general, so I may be way off base.